# Animate mean tilt of all control points

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, properties

[image]

In a curve, each invidivcontrol point has a value called Tilt. Changing the tilt will essentially "twist" the part of the curve. To change the tilt I simply select a control point, and change the tilt value in the N menu. To change the tilt value of multiple control points at once, I just select all and change it in the same way.

The tilt value of an individual control point can be animated. However, when I select all the control points, the tilt value loses its ability to be animated.

**Is there a way to animate the tilt value of all control points without doing it one by one?**

Comment: Don't have time to research it right now, but isn't this what **Drivers** are used for? Can this value be driven, not all can?

Comment: @RonJensen I have tried using drivers but they do not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shipped add-on [*AnimAll*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/animation/animall.html) allows you to do this.

[image]

Alternatives might include giving a subdivided cuboid or array of square rings a *Curve* modifier along the spiral, and rotating the object around its axis of deformation.